# How to identify why mongo cluster crashed

Tags: mongodb

I have Mongo 4.4.10 running on Debian Linux. There is a replica with three nodes. There is no load at all as I am in beta mode yet. But I realized that two nodes have crashed. I cannot find any error in mongo log, probably because I do not know what to search for.

These are some logs from `systemctl`. Mongo restart have succeeded on this node:

```
Dec 19 10:39:56 db2 mongod[22777]: unw_get_proc_name(5559054001F3): unspecified (general) error
Dec 19 10:39:56 db2 mongod[22777]: unw_get_proc_name(5559053FEF30): unspecified (general) error
Dec 19 10:39:56 db2 mongod[22777]: unw_get_proc_name(5559053FF0B3): unspecified (general) error
```

This node has not started correctly:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-14T20:32:39.871+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"10.0.0.3:44290","connectionId":39025946,"connectionCount":17}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-14T20:32:39.871+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn39025946","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"10.0.0.3:44290","client":"conn39025946","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs","version":"3.7.3"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"4.19.0-17-amd64"},"platform":"'Node.js v12.21.0, LE (unified)"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-14T20:32:40.017+01:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4757800, "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Writing fatal message","attr":{"message":"terminate() called. An exception is active; attempting to gather more information"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-14T20:32:40.019+01:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4757800, "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Writing fatal message","attr":{"message":"DBException::toString(): FileStreamFailed: Failed to write to interim file buffer for full-time diagnostic data capture: /var/lib/mongodb/diagnostic.data/metrics.interim.temp\nActual exception type: mongo::error_details::ExceptionForImpl<(mongo::ErrorCodes::Error)39, mongo::AssertionException>\n"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-14T20:32:40.073+01:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31430,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Error collecting stack trace","attr":{"error":"unw_get_proc_name(5627D3821A6A): unspecified (general) error\nunw_get_proc_name(5627D38234F9): unspecified (general) error\nunw_get_proc_name(5627D38206C6): unspecified (general)

Dec 19 22:01:06 www mongod[13698]:   Frame: {"a":"5579FC4F122B","b":"5579FABB2000","o":"193F22B","s":"_ZN5mongo17StorageEngineImplC1EPNS_8KVEngineENS_20StorageEngineOptionsE","s+":"25B"}
Dec 19 22:01:06 www mongod[13698]:   Frame: {"a":"5579FBBE2165","b":"5579FABB2000","o":"1030165","s":"_ZNK5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_117WiredTigerFactory6createERKNS_19StorageGlobalParamsEPKNS_21StorageEngineLockFileE","
Dec 19 22:01:06 www mongod[13698]:   Frame: {"a":"5579FC4FBB57","b":"5579FABB2000","o":"1949B57","s":"_ZN5mongo23initializeStorageEngineEPNS_14ServiceContextENS_22StorageEngineInitFlagsE","s+":"4F7"}
Dec 19 22:01:06 www mongod[13698]:   Frame: {"a":"5579FBB8DF17","b":"5579FABB2000","o":"FDBF17","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_114_initAndListenEPNS_14ServiceContextEi.isra.1584","s+":"3F7"}
Dec 19 22:01:06 www mongod[13698]:   Frame: {"a":"5579FBB91BAB","b":"5579FABB2000","o":"FDFBAB","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_111mongoDbMainEiPPcS2_","s+":"104B"}
Dec 19 22:01:06 www mongod[13698]:   Frame: {"a":"5579FBB03FF9","b":"5579FABB2000","o":"F51FF9","s":"main","s+":"9"}
Dec 19 22:01:06 www mongod[13698]:   Frame: {"a":"7F758908C09B","b":"7F7589068000","o":"2409B","s":"__libc_start_main","s+":"EB"}
Dec 19 22:01:06 www mongod[13698]:   Frame: {"a":"5579FBB8D34A","b":"5579FABB2000","o":"FDB34A","s":"_start","s+":"2A"}
Dec 19 22:01:06 www systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

I need to identify and fix the cause before I go live. What steps shall I take now to find the reason of this failure?

Comment: Mongo logged too much details and log rotation was not set up.

Comment: `..."message":"DBException...` - is it not saying something about an exception?

Comment: The first failure logged was:`Failed to write to interim file buffer for full-time diagnostic data capture: /var/lib/mongodb/diagnostic.data/metrics.interim.temp`.  Is the disk full? did the file permissions get pooched?

Comment: Yes, it was. Mongo log consumed all disk space. It logs every client connection and disconnection by default.